# Error while configuring Access Management with OpenID Connect identity provider

Tags: sites-9.5, azure, access-management

As per Access management documentation I tried to configure OpenID Connect identity provider
By providing the below details

Client Secret = JKg7Q~XX-XXXXA_Ak
Client ID = bd9702f4-e804-4XXX-8f45-bXXXXXb8c
OAuth 2 Autharization  = https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX-33e8-4670-92a8-XXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

After configuring getting below error

IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX-XXXX-4670-92a8-XXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Can you please suggest how to resolve above issue.

Comment: can you share the parameters that you are using for OpenID connect just to verify its everything is ok

Comment: The following parameters has been updated                                                     
"key": "AzureAd",
"name": "AzureAd",
"isEnabled": true,
"description": "AzureAd",
"type": "OpenIdConnect",
"iconUrl": "/AzureAd.png",
"accessControlList": [],
"forwardedClaims": [],
"parameters": {
  "$type": "",
  "clientId": "xxxx",
  "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  "clientSecret": "xxx",
  "endSessionEndpoint": "",
  "sendIdTokenHintDuringLogout": false,
  "separator": "",
  "usernameClaim": "upn",
  "fullNameClaim": "name"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rick was correct. Authority for Azure AD `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenentDomian or TenentId>`

Here is the sample [OpenIdConnect Idp provider JSON example](https://github.com/avmgan/AccessManagementInstallationScript/blob/main/azure-idp-provider-sample.json), In case if you want to install and configure the IDP provider config using the [PowerShell script](https://github.com/avmgan/AccessManagementInstallationScript).

```
    {
    "key": "AzureAd",
    "name": "AzureAd",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "AzureAd",
    "type": "OpenIdConnect",
    "iconUrl": "/access-management/ui/idpIcons/AzureAd.png",
    "accessControlList": [
        {
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Access Management"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Add-ons"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Classic (UI only)"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Experience Space"
                }
            ],
            "apiResources": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Access Management API"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Add-ons API"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tridion Sites Content Manager API"
                }
            ],
            "apiResourceRoles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "forwardedClaims": [],
    "parameters": {
        "$type": "",
        "clientId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx",
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx365.onmicrosoft.com",
        "clientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "endSessionEndpoint": "",
        "responseType": "",
        "sendIdTokenHintDuringLogout": false,
        "separator": "",
        "usernameClaim": "upn",
        "fullNameClaim": "name"
    }
}
```

**Note:** also make sure to configure the access management redirect Url on the azure side.

**Updated:**

**AccessManagement-Service-Install.ps1** PowerShell script only generates the signing certificate and does the installation only for HTTP endpoint.

If you want to [Enabling HTTPS for Access Management running as a Windows service](https://docs.rws.com/816112/775940/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/enabling-https-for-------------access-management-running-as-a-windows-service), after the service installation install the certificate on the server and update the **appsettings.json** as mentioned below, and restart the access management service.

Replace `"URLs": "http://*:80",`

To

```
"Kestrel":  {
  "EndPoints":  {
 
     "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url":  "https://*:443",
          "Certificate":  {
              "Subject":  "*.tridiondemo.com",
              "Store":  "Root",
              "Location":  "LocalMachine"
          }
      }
  }      
}
```

For the Linux system installation, a certificate should be created as a file and a path should be configured. [refer to the documentation](https://docs.rws.com/816112/796701/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/enabling-https-for-------------access-management-running-as-a-linux-daemon).

In case if you looking for the script to generate the certificate to update the config for https, R&D provided a script for Add-on service which can also be re-used for Access Management, here is the script: **[Installation-Media]\Add-on Service\generateCertificate.ps1**

**Note:** To match the **Subject** config to your certificate subject which is installed on the server.

Comment: Hi Velu, I have used the PowerShell script for Access Management installation, since I am not aware of sequence after Access Management installation we connected with our Azure team. Your script works great. Small doubt Can I enable HTTPS Access Management  directly using your PowerShell script by changing the $setupOptions.PORT_ACESSMANAEMENT_SERVICE value as 443.

Comment: No, Updated my answer, I will extend this script to support HTTPS later

Comment: Can the Subject be same Domain as CMS? I am installing Access Management on CMS server. for example if my CMS Url is https://tridiondemo.com can the Subject also be tridiondemo.com

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamudi yes. if you created a certificate with DNS name tridiondemo.com then that certificate subject become tridiondemo.com, In case if you are using a wildcard certificate then need to use *.tridiondemo.com

Comment: Once installed redirect url of access management showed as "http://localhost:84/access-management/azuread/signout-oidc" after enabling HTTPS should we configure in azure as  "https://localhost:443/access-management/azuread/signout-oidc" or do we need to configure domain name or localhost works?

Comment: It depends which URL you are going to use and configure in CME it has to be, localhost URL can also work.  https://localhost/access-management/azuread/signin-oidc, make sure to add signin-oidc for the redirect, not signout, makes sure whatever the access management URL you are going to configure in CME same domain should be configured in azure redirect url.

Comment: few clarifications: 1. As per documentation we should not install Access Management in Same as CMS server if we configure "local host" in another server CMS may not be able to access the configured URL, will it not create any issue? 2. If we configure localhost will Azure Ad recognizes that URL and provide access token? 3. Can I use port 8443 instead 443 to configure windows service in CMS server.

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamud localhost setup is only if you install everything on one server. For customer environments, better to install access and add-services in separate shared servers. expose it with a DNS name to make sure it's accessible to CME and DXD services. yes you can use https://<your-accessmangement-host>:8443

Comment: @velu , Client requested that we need to configure same domain as CMS for Access management also, so we tried to install Access management on CMS server with port :84 and tried to utilize IIS rewrite module to redirect to "localhost:84" if our CMS url which hosted on 443 contains "access-management" by SSL offloading, that didnt worked, can you please suggest if there is any other way I can achieve the requirement

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamudi, If the answer helped to fix your issue, please upvote and accept the answer, to answer your question. if you want to keep it in the same CMS server then still possible, but keep it like that, CME is in 443 it should be accessible https://cms-domain.com/ for access management keep it https://cms-domain.com:85/access-management, don't use a proxy redirect. if you looking to keep running both 443 port it's not advised.

Comment: Small clarification: Can we configure Non SSL Url as Redirect Url in Azure

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamudi: It depends. if your access management planned to run in HTTPS. then you have to keep the HTTPS redirect URL in azure, if it's HTTP then yes you can keep the HTTP redirect URL

Comment: @Velu Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Authority for Azure AD is supposed to look like this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdl365.onmicrosoft.com`

So, excluding the `/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` suffix you have in the URL.